# Can't add foreign key users table in mysql Workbench

Tags: foreign-keys, mysql-workbench

I'm having a problem and don't have much time so solve it.

I have thoses tables in my database, one called wall and the other is users.
For the wall table, I can add a foreign like you can see : [image]

 But in the users table, I can't and I don't know why. Both tables are empty.
Here you can see the users table : [image]

 And this is the error code I get :
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I think there is not possible to create foreign key to the same table.
In this SQL you change table 'user' and add to this table foreign key from 'user' table.
If I'm wrong please correct me.

Here is example:

```
alter table `wall` add constraint `id_user_constraint_name` foreign key (`id_user`) references `users`(id);
```

If you don't have a 'id_user' column use this sql:

```
alter table `wall` add column id_user bigint;
```

Comment: Not sure to understand everything there. So I can create FK for the wall table but not for the users table? Using the 'id' row

Comment: In this sql you modify 'user' table.